# DynamicJAXBContextFactory.createContextFromXSD fails to load SchemaMetadata

Tags: java, jaxb, moxy

I'm using the `DynamicJAXBContextFactory.createContextFromXSD` method to create a `jaxbcontext`from an `xsd`.

It works fine when I instantiate all classes from a junit test, but when I call the same classes deployed on a glassfish 4 server, the class `org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.dynamic.metadata.SchemaMetadata` can't be found!
Running GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.0 (build 89) with Eclipselink 2.5.0
I have tested with nightly build glassfish-4.0.1-b04-02_04_2014-ml with Eclipselink 2.5.1, it's the same fault there.

I downloaded the source code and during debug I could set a `log.debugflag` to 4 and got a detailed description of the cause:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: `***` Class 'org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.dynamic.metadata.SchemaMetadata' was not found because bundle org.eclipse.persistence.core [211] does not import 'org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.dynamic.metadata' even though bundle org.eclipse.persistence.moxy [216] does export it. Additionally, the class is also available from the system class loader. There are two fixes: 1) Add an import for 'org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.dynamic.metadata' to bundle org.eclipse.persistence.core [211]; imports are necessary for each class directly touched by bundle code or indirectly touched, such as super classes if their methods are used. 2) Add package 'org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.dynamic.metadata' to the 'org.osgi.framework.bootdelegation' property; a library or VM bug can cause classes to be loaded by the wrong class loader. The first approach is preferable for preserving modularity. `***`

I added `org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.dynamic.metadata` to the `org.osgi.framework.bootdelegation` property. Then the class loaded, but now it't can't find the constructor!

I debug the `org.eclipse.persistence.internal.security.PrivilegedAccessHelper.getConstructorFor` method, (see code below), but it can't find the constructor even if they look the same to me!
The `parameterType` is class `org.eclipse.persistence.dynamic.DynamicClassLoader`,
the `argType` is class `org.eclipse.persistence.dynamic.DynamicClassLoader`,
but somehow the methods `parameterType.isAssignableFrom(argType)) && (!argType.isAssignableFrom(parameterType)` fail if the code runs in glassfish 4 but works if run from a junit-test.

I don't know why it won't work, can someone help me please?

And the detailed message suggest that the number 1) solution should be used, i.e

> 1) Add an import for 'org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.dynamic.metadata' to bundle org.eclipse.persistence.core [211];

Is this a bug in eclipselink, if so can someone fix it?

Here is the code for the method:

```
public static Constructor getConstructorFor(final Class javaClass, final Class[] args, final boolean shouldSetAccessible) throws NoSuchMethodException {
    Constructor result = null;
    try {
        result = javaClass.getConstructor(args);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException missing) {
        // Search for any constructor with the same number of arguments and assignable types.
        for (Constructor constructor : javaClass.getConstructors()) {
            if (constructor.getParameterTypes().length == args.length) {
                boolean found = true;
                for (int index = 0; index < args.length; index++) {
                    Class parameterType = Helper.getObjectClass(constructor.getParameterTypes()[index]);
                    Class argType = Helper.getObjectClass(args[index]); 
                    if ((!parameterType.isAssignableFrom(argType))
                        && (!argType.isAssignableFrom(parameterType))) {
                        found = false; 
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (found) {
                    result = constructor;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (result == null) {
            throw missing;
        }
    }
    if (shouldSetAccessible) {
        result.setAccessible(true);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MOXy's support for bootstrapping a dynamic JAXB model from an XML Schema does not currently work in an OSGi environment.

For this feature MOXy leverages code from the JAXB reference implementation.  Part of the code that is responsible for generating Java classes from an XML Schema.  This code gave us problems when we tried to OSFi-ify it, therefore we couldn't expose the code that depended on it though OSGi.